# publish app with expansion file

Tags: android, publish

I have referred many related links but i was not successful yet .

I have an app with 615 mb , so i have optimized such that my main .apk has 24 mb and rest in the extension file as .zip . Now i could not find where to upload my extension .zip file in the Play Store .

I have referred :

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_publishing_an_application_on_google_play

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

can you please suggest me where to upload this extension file . It would be helpful if any tutorial or step by step process is explained .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: If you solved, please post a answer.

Comment: @Sisso : Just upload your app in the production , once it gets completed it will automatically ask for the expansion file(if any you can upload or else just ignore )

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the extension file upload simple don't appear. I have solved it by switching to advanced mode, unpublish the current version, and when I upload the new version it ask for extension file.